# Validate if Date1 > Date2

Tags: datetime, forms

If I have 2 date fields in a content type: Event Start Date and Action Start Date.

Is there a way to validate that Action Start Date is later/greater than Event Start Date while creating the content?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the [Date module](https://drupal.org/project/date) you can create one field and configure it to use a start and end date. Then the module will validate the end date is greater than start date automatically for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but actually I want both to be separate as I want to name them differently. You can consider both of them as start date but one should be after the another. May be I should rephrase my question.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Date restrictions](https://drupal.org/project/date_restrictions) module. This is how to achieve what youre looking for:

- Enable Date Restrictions Min/Max and Date Restrictions Host Entity modules.
- Edit your target field (Action Start Date).
- Expand More settings and values » Restrictions » Minimun date.
- Choose option "Host entity: get fixed date from a field in the host entity" and select your source field (Event Start Date).

This will restrict the minimum value for the target field to the value of the source field.

If you're using date popup, it will restrict available days in the target field's popup, also if the source field changes, the target will be updated via ajax to reflect the new restriction.

Comment: It looks to be the one I need but I use drupal 6, is backporting to version 6 possible?

Comment: Backporting Date Restrictions (or the portion involved here) is probably fasible but it seems hard, and a no rewarding task to do. You better look for another solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

> 1. hook_form_alter your content type.
> 2. Add custom validation handler to it.
> 3. In the validation callback try using date diff as below.

```
   // Pass the date field value while instantiating date object.
   $event_start = new DateTime('2013-01-26');
   $action_start  = new DateTime('2013-07-26');
   $date_diff = $event_start->diff($action_start);
   $date_diff->format('%R'); // use for point out relation: smaller/greater
   $date_diff->days;
```

if action date is larger/greater then $date_diff->format('%R'); will return '+' else it will return '-'.

Comment: It is far to hard to read this:
Why not using simple comparison operators?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961074/how-do-i-compare-two-datetime-objects-in-php-5-2-8